# how to get user id in flickr from username/useremail using Python?

Tags: python, flickr

I am trying to fetch a set of photos, by album, for a user on flickr using the Python `flickrapi` (http://stuvel.eu/media/flickrapi-docs/documentation/). Their example uses a numeric ID for the user:

```
import flickrapi

api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key)
photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='73509078@N00', per_page='10')
sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='73509078@N00')
```

How can I get this numeric ID for a user, based on the user's flickr username or email address? It appears that this does it: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.findByUsername.html  but I am not sure how to call it from the python flickrapi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
flickr.people.findByUsername(user_id='73509078@N00')
```

That should works.